# Declaring dynamic array of structure globally

Tags: c++, struct

I am working on a project which contain a lot of function and I used this struct

```
struct client {
string Name;
long long accountid;
long double Balance;
string socialnumber;}
user[1000];
```

but now I want to use Dynamic array 
I tried to use

```
client* user;    
user=new client[maxsize];
```

but it can be only declared on main function 
How can I declare it globally to be used in all functions ?

Comment: What do you mean, can only be *declared* on main function? `user = new client[maxsize];` is not a declaration.

Comment: you meant to trigger user.user ?? the array variable within your struct

Comment: My guess is `maxsize` is only known in main. But the OP does not understand you can have a pointer initialized to nullptr then set it again later. However why do you need a global in the first place? Pass the pointer from `main()` to the functions that need it.

Comment: Save yourself some future heartache and **do not intentionally introduce global state** into your program.